# Redis //Benchmark tool// How to enable Asynchronous Testing

Tags: database, asynchronous, redis

I am testing Redis (version: 0.8.8.384) using the benchmark tool, and the redis-server.exe that is included in the zip package locally.

I have noticed that the benchmark tool has a synchronous behavior with the Redis Server (every command is send from client to server only when the previous command was acknowledged from the server). 
Is there a way to change the behavior to asynchronous?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the Windows fork of Redis is similar to the official project, the answer is no - `redis-benchmark` is single-threaded.

Comment: Thanks for your responce Itamar!